# Jasny bootstrap Off Canvas menu: how to force menu slide under the navbar?

Tags: javascript, css, jasny-bootstrap

I want to add static (not movable) header to the [off canvas push menu](http://codepen.io/rugor/pen/eiyzh).

here is what I have for now: [codePen link](http://codepen.io/Qvatra/pen/vEMvrb)

```
<span>This text should not move</span>

<div class="navmenu navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-left offcanvas">
      <a class="navmenu-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      <ul class="nav navmenu-nav">
        <li><a href="../navmenu/">Slide in</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="./">Push</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navmenu-reveal/">Reveal</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-offcanvas/">Off canvas navbar</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar navbar-default"> -------------------- navbar should not move -----------------------
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target=".navmenu" data-canvas=".container">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <h1>Content that should move. Menu should slide from the left side UNDER the navbar</h1>
    </div>
```

the problem is that I don't know how to force menu slide under the 'navbar'.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `top:120px` to make it appear below the navbar

```
.navmenu-fixed-left, .navmenu-fixed-right, .navbar-offcanvas {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1050;
  top: 120px;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/mohamedrias/pen/XJQoOV)**

Comment: well yeah that is the straight forward css solution but I have responsive layout and header+navbar height would be different for different resolutions..

Comment: We can use media queries in that case.

Comment: and by the way in your demo example menu appears from nowhere but i need sliding as in 'off canvas push menu link'. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Use css3 transition for that offcanvas element. It will give you similar animation.